# HDMI Issue - Can't disconnect from TV/External Display

Tags: 14.04, display, hdmi, wakeup

So here is the situation..

When I first came back to ubuntu (14.04) I experienced a fail at wake from suspention. My Hp Pavilion G4 would turn on as expected but screen would be off (not blank, notebook display would be off). A short search led me to fix it by turning to proprietary video drivers.

Recently i started experiencing this again.. This time i noticed by chance that when I tried to resume my laptop with it still hooked to HDMI it would work alright, but laptop screen would still be off.
At the same time, audio recognizes HDMI speakers from boot when no HDMI cable is hooked.

I tried hooking/unhooking cable from laptop with it on and off. Figured it had to be something with the HDMI slot. But nothing happened. problem persists.

Any input is welcome.